# When are entire functions surjective?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Is there some useful criterion to determine whether or not an entire function is surjective?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe Picard's theorem is of help
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem

Comment: Indeed. And it is surjective if and only if it not of the form 
$e^{h(z)}+\alpha$ for a suitable constant $\alpha$ and a suitable entire function $h(z)$.

Comment: +1. And to show this, it's probably worth looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Comment: I don't see how Picard's theorem, or Roland Bacher's remark, is useful in practice to determine whether an entire function is surjective.  

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: Hence the 'maybe' in the post. I was thinking about a useful/practical criterion but nothing came to mind.

Comment: But certainly if there is no $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z) - \alpha}$ is entire, we can conclude that $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: @Saul : We can conclude that $f$ IS surjective. 

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270804/surjective-entire-functions/270818#270818