# Surjective entire functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

If I have an entire function give as a power series $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iz^i$, is there a way/technique to check if the function is surjective? Weierstarss factorization theorem gives that $f$ is not surjective if and only if $f=\exp(g)+c$ for some $\require{cancel}\cancel{surjective}$ entire function $g$. However I don't know how to check this. Is there, for example, some known result that gives the surjectivity of $f$ depending on the behavior (rate of convergence?) of the coefficients?

This question was asked before, but did not receive an answer at the time.

[When are entire functions surjective?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26903/when-are-entire-functions-surjective)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your statement that if $f$ is not surjective, then $f=e^g+c$ where $g$ is surjective is wrong: $g$ does not have to be surjective. Example: $f(z)=e^{e^z}$. By the way, this example permits an infinite iteration: there
is an infinite sequence of entire functions $f_n$ such that all of them are zero-free, and $e^{f_{n+1}}=f_n$.

There are various results which imply that $f$ is surjective, you have to be more specific, what kind of criterion you want. In terms of growth of coefficients,
if  $$\rho:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\log n}{-\log|a_n|}<1$$
then $f$ is surjective. If this is equal to $1$, but
$$\sigma:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}n|a_n|^{1/n}=0,$$
then $f$ is surjective.

Moreover, if $f$ is not surjective then either $\rho$ is a positive integer and
$\sigma$ is non-zero and finite, or $\rho=\infty$.
This gives a pretty strong sufficient condition of surjectivity in terms of coefficients.

Another types of conditions can be obtained when you know something about $f$ beyond the coefficients. For example, if $f$ has infinitely many zeros, but not too many:
$$\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\log n(r)}{\log r}<\rho,$$
where $n(r)$ is the number of zeros in the disk $|z|\leq r$, then $f$ is surjective. This can be very much refined, if needed.

One can give very many other sufficient conditions in terms of coefficients, for example if many of the coefficients are $0$ (gap series), and in other terms. For example, one can combine growth conditions with gap conditions. But the only reasonable necessary and sufficient condition is that $f=e^g+c$ with some entire $g$.

Reference: B. Ya. Levin books on entire functions (any of the two of them).

Comment: This is exactly the type of conditions I was looking for, thank you. From what I can understand, the first conditions mean that $|a_n|$ does not go to $0$ too fast. However in my case $\rho=\infty$, I will look in the reference you kindly suggested, perhaps there will be something helpful there. By the way, if $f$ has finitely, but non-zero, many zeros (or any other value), Picard implies that it must be surjective right? So another way would be to show that it takes a certain value finitely many times.

Comment: My second criterion generalizes the case of finitely many zeros. Speaking of $\rho=\infty$, it is more difficult, but if you give the exact statement that you need I may try to help.

Comment: The (family of)  series I am looking at is a bit strange. Consider a $n\times n$ matrix $A$, two length $1$ column vectors $x$ and $y$ and assume the function $f(z)=\sum z^n x^{T}A^n y$ is entire for any choice of such $x$ and $y$ ($A$ is fixed). I want to conclude that $f$ is surjective or constant. Probably it cannot be done in general, as the result will depend on the choice of $x$, $y$, and $A$.

Comment: Your function is not entire, unless it is a polynomial. Your coefficients cannot decrease faster than a geometric progression.

Comment: Is it not possible that $||A^n||^{1/n}\to 0$, so $\sum z^n A^n$ will be entire?

Comment: Not possible unless $A^n=0$ for some $n$.

Comment: Oh, I see (I think), $||A^n||^{1/n}\to 0$ already implies $A$ is nilpotent, so the series is a polynomial,

Comment: I guess the question makes sense in the context of $l_2$, with $A$ being an operator such that $||A^n||^{1/n}\to 0$. In this case $A$ does not have to be nilpotent. I guess in this case surjectivity could go either way.

Comment: This is not an entire function, whatever is the context. Your series has finite radius of convergence, unless it is a polynomial.

Comment: Why is that?  Since  $||\sum z^nA^n||\leq\sum z^n||A^n||$ and the RHS converges for all $z$ when $||A^n||^{1/n}\to 0$, it follows that LHS is convergent. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: Use the Jordan form to see that $\| A^n\|^{1/n}$ cannot tend to $0$.

Comment: I think it does for a quasi-nilpotent operator, it follows from Gelfand formula for the  spectral radius.

Comment: There is a small typo in the formula for $\sigma$, it should be $\limsup_{n\to\infty}n|a_n|^{1/n}$.

Comment: @Martin R I think there should be $\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\log n(r)}{\log r}<\rho$ instead of $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n(r)}{\log r}<\rho$ as well

Comment: @Nomas: Thanks I corrected the misprint.

Comment: @Markus: It was assumed that $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix. If the spectral radius is $0$ it is nilpotent.